# Code not saving files, but no errors

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying to run a code to pull in data from yahoo finance. I don't get any errors but yet I can't find the files anywhere on my computer. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Josh

This is what I'm using now, and I'm getting a lot of 'oh no's. I tried using the number 5 and the number 6. Still nothing:

```
import urllib2
import time

stockstoPull = 'CJES','BP','MSFT','TSLA','GOOG'

def pullData(stock):
    fileLine = '/Users/Josh/Documents/Python'+stock+'.txt'
    urltovisit ='http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
    sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(urltovisit).read()
    splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

    for eachLine in splitSource:
        splitLine = eachLine.split(',')
        if len(splitLine) == 5:
            if 'values' not in eachLine:
                saveFile = open(fileLine,'a')
                linetoWrite = eachLine+'\n'
                saveFile.write(linetoWrite)
        else:
            print('oh no')

    print('Pulled', stock)
    print('...')
    time.sleep(.5)

for eachStock in stockstoPull:     
    pullData(eachStock)
```

Fixed, thanks everyone who helped.

Comment: Your code is not entering `if` condition so nothing happens. Also your `if` indentation in above code has error. May be you require `if len(splitLine) == 6 and 'values' not in eachLine:`

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug in your code. I believe `if len(splitLine) == 6:` should be `if len(splitLine) == 5:`

For example if you go to:
http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/CJES/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv

and read the first line you try to split:
20120904,19.2400,20.3900,19.1200,20.1500,901600

It actually splits into a 5 element list using the delimiter '.'.
20120904,19
2400,20
3900,19
1200,20
1500,901600

I modified your code to run in Python 3.3.2 and this worked for me and successfully pulled all the stock data. Before I made the change to `if len(splitLine) == 5:` your code was not entering the first `if` statement because `len(splitLine)` was never 6.

Here is the code that worked for me. Note that this is Python 3.3 so I had to change some things to make it work but it should work for you using the same logic of just changing the `len(splitLine)` thing.

```
import urllib.request
import time

stockstoPull = 'CJES','BP','MSFT','TSLA','GOOG'

def pullData(stock):
    fileLine = stock+'.txt'
    urltovisit ='http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(urltovisit) as f:
        sourceCode = f.read(100000).decode('utf-8')
    splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

    for eachLine in splitSource:
        splitLine = eachLine.split('.')
        if len(splitLine) == 5:
            if 'values' not in eachLine:
                saveFile = open(fileLine,'a')
                linetoWrite = eachLine+'\n'
                saveFile.write(linetoWrite)
        else:
            print('oh no')

    print('Pulled', stock)
    print('...')
    time.sleep(.5)

for eachStock in stockstoPull:     
    pullData(eachStock)
```

Comment: There are six pieces of data, separated by 5 commas, is that how you would do it? When I run it your way, I get back: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: Well that is because I was using a python 3.3 module urlib.request...You are probably using Python 2.7. I told you I had to change some things to make it work. Your given code splits the lines by periods, not commas. If you want 6 pieces of data, separated by 5 commas, do splitLine = eachLine.split(',')      
if len(splitLine) == 6:

Comment: I thought I reversed everything you did.

Comment: You don't need to use my code. Just change your code! There's literally two lines you would have to change. do splitLine = eachLine.split(',') if len(splitLine) == 6: I just wanted to show what worked for me in Python 3.3. :\

Comment: Thats what I did. It still isn't working, sorry if I didn't make that clear

Comment: Use print statements to debug your if statements in a simple way. Make sure that your code is going inside all of your if statements where you want it to. It is very likely that your code is just not reaching that file output point since your file i/o code seems to be correct. You may also want to try using open(fileLine,'w') instead of open(fileLine, 'a').

Comment: I debugged it using the 'oh no' print like you used and it keeps doing it. I also tried using the if statements exactly as you said and they aren't working.

Comment: Okay I'm still getting the errors, but it's saving the files with only the last line on the page. Is there something that could cause it to skip all the others?

Comment: Yes you are probably doing open(fileLine, 'w') and you should switch it back to open(fileLine, 'a') so that it appends instead of overwriting the files.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much for the help. For some reason, it's still saying 'oh no' though...

Comment: Well it will say 'oh no' because not all lines will have len(splitLine) == 6. You should take that print statement out of the code, since I was just using it to debug.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the help. I'm going to practice on some simpler codes until I get the hand of this better. Started python (my first language) about 72 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've ensured that `stock` is a string. If the program runs as you expect, the files should save at the same directory as the program.

If it's not running as expected, you can start by noticing that you're creating the file under a `try:`, and then a `for`, and then two `if`s. If any of these lines don't work as expected (e.g. `sourceCode` doesn't split as planned, or the `if` conditions are not met), the file won't be created, so no use looking for it. Test out first whether these lines work as you want them.

Also, it looks like you missed an indentation following `if len(splitLine) == 6:`?

Comment: I combined the two if lines like he said about. I'm running it with the file type specified as well. I'm getting back 'invalid synatx' on the 'except Exception' line.

Edit: Nevermind. I changed the indent on the line mentioned above, ran it using %paste and it ran without errors, but still no files. Any idea?

Comment: Well, that's because that line is really wrong syntax. It doesn't make any sense in python. Edit: that line is still wrong syntax, except you're not reaching it any more.

Answer (score 0):

you can use find command to find the file that you have created:

```
sudo find / 'GOOG.txt'
```

However, remember to add the absolute path to your python file path.
In this case:

```
fileLine = '/home/...'+ stock+'.txt'   # /home/... could be your home folder
```

(Note, if you are using IDE like eclipse, you might find those files in your project folder)

Answer (score 0):

```
In your data len(splitline) at most 5, So your if condition is false every time.


 if len(splitLine) == 6:
        if 'values' not in eachLine:
            saveFile = open(fileLine,'w')
            linetoWrite = eachLine+'\n'
            saveFile.write(linetoWrite)
so this line never executed and your file was not saved as
saveFile.write(linetoWrite) statement is inside the if condition.
```

Comment: I rewrote it using 6 and it isn't working. Look at my edited post

Answer (score 0):

If your filename is incorrect, for example, a mispelling or misdirection, it will not save the file, or show an error. You can check it by saving it with commands in the shell, and if it works, it will return True. If not, check the file and path you were submitting. The path must exist before saving to it.

Comment: Check also to be sure the '+' is not fouling up the filename if you are including it. If all else fails, remove that symbol from the filename. It may fix it.